# Get App Settings Using Azure Node SDK

Tags: node.js, azure

We have a node.js web application running in Microsoft Azure and need to modify the App Settings of the instance program programmatically. We have setup a simple project in Visual Studio in order to test the functionality of the Azure Node SDK but are unable to find a way to retrieve the App Settings themselves using the getSite class.

This could be because we are not calling App Settings correctly however the documentation provided here: http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-arm-website/latest/Sites.html#getSite simply states **propertiesToInclude** but doesn't list what the properties could be so we pretty much took a guess. Our code is below:

```
var msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
var webSiteManagementClient = require('azure-arm-website');
msRestAzure.interactiveLogin(function (err, credentials) {
    var client = new webSiteManagementClient(credentials, "252a971e-c5c0-4e34-84a3-58a5b1e5c7f9");
    client.sites.getSite("*****resourcegroup", "*********service", {propertiesToInclude:'appSettings'}, function (err, result, request, response) {
        console.log('Err:' + err);
        console.log('Result:' + JSON.stringify(result));
        console.log('Requrest:' + JSON.stringify(request));
        console.log('Response:' + JSON.stringify(response));
    });
});
```

If the property is something specific or if we should be using a different class entirely please let me know as any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `App Settings` in your web app, please use function [`listSiteAppSettings(resourceGroupName, name, optionsopt, callback)`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-arm-website/latest/Sites.html#listSiteAppSettings), e.g.

```
client.sites.listSiteAppSettings("*****resourcegroup", "*********service", function (err, result, request, response) {
    console.log('Result:' + JSON.stringify(result.properties));
});
```